# Passing `nil` to method using default named parameters

Tags: ruby, named-parameters

On a Rails project, I am gathering a hash with 10-15 key-value pairs, and passing it to a class (service object) for instantiation. The object properties should be set from the values in the hash except when there is no value (or `nil`). In this case, the property would desirably get set to a default value.

Instead of checking whether every value in the hash is not `nil` before creating an object, I would like to find a more efficient way of doing this.

I'm trying to use named parameters with default values. I don't know if this makes sense, but I would like to use the default value when the parameter is called with `nil`. I created a test for this functionality:

```
class Taco
  def initialize(meat: "steak", cheese: true, salsa: "spicy")
    @meat = meat
    @cheese = cheese
    @salsa = salsa
  end
  def assemble
    "taco with: #@meat + #@cheese + #@salsa"
  end
end

options1 = {:meat => "chicken", :cheese => false, :salsa => "mild"}
chickenTaco = Taco.new(options1)
puts chickenTaco.assemble
# => taco with: chicken + false + mild

options2 = {}
defaultTaco = Taco.new(options2)
puts defaultTaco.assemble
# => taco with: steak + true + spicy

options3 = {:meat => "pork", :cheese => nil, :salsa => nil}
invalidTaco = Taco.new(options3)
puts invalidTaco.assemble
# expected => taco with: pork + true + spicy
# actual => taco with: pork +  +
```

Comment: thanks for the formatting help sawa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow a Object-Oriented approach, you could isolate your defaults in a separate method and then use `Hash#merge`:

```
class Taco
  def initialize (args)
    args = defaults.merge(args)
    @meat   = args[:meat]
    @cheese = args[:cheese]
    @salsa  = args[:salsa]
  end

  def assemble
     "taco with: #{@meat} + #{@cheese} + #{@salsa}"
  end

  def defaults
   {meat: 'steak', cheese: true, salsa: 'spicy'}
  end  
end
```

Then following the suggestion by @sawa (thanks), use Rails' `Hash#compact` for your input hashes that have explicitly defined `nil` values and you will have the following output:

```
taco with: chicken + false + mild
taco with: steak + true + spicy
taco with: pork + true + spicy
```

**EDIT:**

If you do not want to use Rails' wonderful `Hash#compact` method, you can use Ruby's `Array#compact` method. Replacing the first line within the `initialize` method to:

```
args = defaults.merge(args.map{|k, v| [k,v] if v != nil }.compact.to_h)
```

Comment: Using `Hash#merge` in addition to `Hash#compact` is a great method of ensuring my object gets default instead of `nil` values for it's properties. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Once you pass a value with a named parameter, access to the default value for that parameter is gone for that method call.

You either have to (i) assign the default value not in the method profile but in the method body as in sagarpandya82's answer, or (ii) remove the `nil` values before passing the arguments to the method like this using Rails' `Hash#compact`:

```
options3 = {:meat => "pork", :cheese => nil, :salsa => nil}
invalidTaco = Taco.new(options3.compact)
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as I couldn't get the OPs desired ouput. If you know how to fix feel free to incorporate into your answer.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I don't see anything wrong with your answer. At least, it is much better than the accepted answer, which doesn't even take care of the default values (other than in an afterthought response to the OP's comment).

Comment: OP wanted `taco with: chicken + false + mild` for the first string. My code prints `taco with: chicken + true + mild`. That's the only reason. Can you see a fix?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I see. Use `nil?`.

Comment: Thanks @sawa, but I think using `||` in this case is flawed, so I've submitted a new answer which incorporates your answer.

Comment: @sawa I really like the Hash#compact method and it's use in this case. Thanks for shedding more light on the Ruby language!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think keyword arguments would be appropriate in your case. It seems a Hash is a better fit.

```
class Taco
    attr_accessor :ingredients

    def initialize(ingredients = {})
        @ingredients = ingredients
    end

    def assemble
        "taco with: #{ingredients[:meat]} + #{ingredients[:cheese]} + #{ingredients[:salsa]}"
    end
end
```

You can even shorter the `assemble` method to list all the ingredients

```
def assemble
    string = "taco with: " + ingredients.values.join(" + ")
end
```

And it will work as you'd expect

```
options1 = {:meat => "chicken", :cheese => false, :salsa => "mild"}
chicken_taco = Taco.new(options1)
puts chicken_taco.assemble() # output: taco with: chicken + false + mild
```

It is worth to mention that Ruby prefers `chicken_tacos` over `chickenTacos`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Is there any way I could provide default values for some of the `ingredients` hash keys you as you mentioned in your answer? For instance, if `meat` is not given as an ingredient it will still print `taco with: {default_meat} + {other_ingredient_a} + ...`?

Comment: `ingredients[:meat] ||= "default meat"` will allow you to conditionally assign a default value for that key if none was given.